# How to make the java application run as service that opens automatically at particular time

Tags: java, windows, swing, awt

I am developing a windows based java application, One of the requirements for this application is, when this application is installed on other machines, it should open automatically at specified time and user has to select some option on the application, If the user didn't choose the options and close/minimize the application, the application should pop-up again after some time.

Please let me know how do I achieve the above functionality.

Comment: You can run it on tray mode.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, because of security reasons windows services are prevented from interaction with users via Gui - one should make significant efforts to show window from service process. You described process that unlikely may be called windows service, rather it should be **scheduled**. Some kind of Windows port of **cron** will help you. For instance, [nnCron](http://www.nncron.ru/). It can in particular display, hide, close, kill, minimize, maximize and hide specified windows to system tray. Just in case, to fully answer your question - turning process (that has no GUI and was not created as service) into windows service is easy with help of srvany. **Srvany.exe** allows any Windows application to run as a service.